# Is the graphical hardware/CPU settings UI on UEFI mainboards an UEFI application (in the sense of the spec)?

Tags: uefi

In the last weeks I studied the UEFI spec, tianocore/edk2, and built + booted edk2/OVMF in QEMU. UEFI knows about UEFI applications (section 2.1.2 UEFI Application). I know that examples for UEFI applications are boot managers and (OS-specific) boot loaders, that benefit from the UEFI boot time services (very basic OS-like system, with allocator etc.).

I'd love to know: The regular end consumer understands UEFI as the *"nice graphical settings interface where you can use your mouse and click around to change CPU clock settings, RAM timings, and other hardware information"* on their (gaming PCs) mainboard.

From a technical aspect: Is this settings menu an UEFI application that uses UEFI boot time services?

Is there any example code for such an application on Github?

Answer (score 2):

Yes these applications are UEFI applications following the specification, take a look at [project mu](https://github.com/microsoft/mu_oem_sample) for sample code.